# issue while storing a string having newline breaks in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a textbox whose value i am storing in json as follows

```
description=JSON.stringify($("#textarea").val());
```

and then i am storing it in a json object as follows

```
myObj['description']=description;
```

The Whole Json now gets stored in my mysql db.The issue i am facing whenever i try to fetch whole json and repopulate the text area with description i get following string

```
Your Name Is ABC\nYou Live in\nYour Phone number Is\n
```

Basically now my text area doesn't recognize the \n as linebreak

Comment: May i ask why you stringify the text from the textarea?

Comment: Yes you only need stringify to encode myObj.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the html contents with jquery like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#loading-area").html('Your Name Is ABC\nYou Live in\nYour Phone number Is\n').wrap('<pre />');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button>Change content of all p elements</button>

<p id="loading-area">This is the loading para.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When storing a string in JSON, the `new line` is stored as the `\n` character not rendered.

To render the `new line` inside `textarea`:

```js
$('#id-for-element').html(myObj['description'].replaceAll('\n', '&#13;&#10;'));
```

HTML will parse and render `&#13;&#10;` as `new line`.
[HTML Char Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)